# Permission forbidden on localhost with apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, lamp, ubuntu-13.04

Here is what I am trying to do.

I tried to add another folder to apache and I get the following error when trying to acces `testing/index.html`.

The idea is that I would like to have for every customer a folder like `/home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/[PROJECT NAME]/CustomerProjects/website/dist`.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at testing Port 80
```

Here are the steps that I followed:

**Step1:**

```
sudo chmod a+x /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist
```

**Step2:**

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist

sudo chmod -R 775 /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist
```

**Step3:**

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```

**Step4:**

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

**Step5:**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache/sites-available/default /etc/apache/sites-available/testing
```

I edited the file `/etc/apache/sites-available/testing` so it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName testing
    DocumentRoot /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step6:**

I edited hosts ("/etc/hosts") so it looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 
127.0.0.1       testing


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**Step7:**

```
sudo a2ensite testing
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I searched for about 2 hours on the internet but I can't figure out what went wrong.
All the pages that I found following the same steps as described above.

I know there are similar questions here on the internet, but the answer is to change permission to the directory which I did on **Step2**.

I am sorry if this is really a duplicate but I could't find the right answer.

Thank you!

PS. I asked this also on AskUbuntu but didn't get any answers so I'm trying my luck here.

**Edit:**

There isn't much on the error log or the access log.

**On the `access.log`:**

```
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:28 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22   (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:29 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:31 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:32 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:33 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:34 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:35 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:23 +0300] "POST /wordpress-testing/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1376123003.7026669979095458984375 HTTP/1.0" 200 705 "-" "WordPress/3.6; http://localhost/wordpress-testing"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:36 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:37 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:23:38 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2013:11:31:32 +0300] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 485 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"
```

And the last line repeats for about 200 rows.

**On the `error.log`:**

**1. This lines repeat from time to time.**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525   /msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Aug 10 13:06:42 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Aug 10 13:07:36 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Aug 10 13:07:37 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

**2. And this is the predominant error. (hundreds of lines)**

```
[Sat Aug 10 13:07:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant items from your apache accesslog and errorlog?

Comment: I included them.

Answer (score 1):

There are directories above `/home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist/`
that are overidding the permissions. Try modifying the root directory to

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

While not a desirable solution that can help weed out where you're getting blocked. I would then try a mixture of `Allow` and `Deny` statements in the root directory until you get an acceptable blend of security and functionality.

Comment: I tried this, but still not working.

Comment: throw in an `allow from all` in the `/` then maybe? The basic idea is too loosen the permissions within apache to identify the configuration directive that's got you blocked. Is there a httpd.conf anywhere in the apache ServerRoot that might have be tripping you up?

Comment: Actually I am going to downvote myself, since I've lead you astray. The error-log infers this http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied so a file level permissions error. Although not recommending this for production, chmod 777 if you're willing to try anything to get it working

Comment: or chmod 644 just the file /index.html for starters

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and still not workig. There was a httpd.conf but it had nothing to block me, anyway  I even commented everything on there. Also I tried to move everything to Work1 and ran chmod 777 for Work1 and still nothing.

Comment: As inetplumber said, the error log specifies the problem lies in file permissions, not Apache config. 

If one of the higher folders has `neagoe` as owner and 700 permissions (for example), the file higher up in the file tree will always be denied access. Could you run a `chmod 777 /home/neagoe/Work -R`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that all directories leading to the final directory are accessible by Apache.

```
/home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist
```

Most commonly, the home directory (/home/neagoe) will have 750 or 700 permission to prevent other users from accessing it. That will be a problem for Apache.

If that's the case, you can `chmod 755` it (consider if there are any security risks in doing so in your environment first) or `chmod 750` (remember to add Apache to the group that owns the directories in this case).